# Using LINQ to generate Highchart column table data

Tags: c#, linq, highcharts

I have a list of article data `List<Article>`

```
class Article
{
  ....
  public string Author{get; set}
  public int ReadingNumber{get; set}
  public int LikeNumber{get; set}
  public int ForwardingNumber{get; set}
  ....
}
```

inputData

```
List<Article> input = new List<Article>
        {
            new Article { Author = "author1", ReadingNumber = 49, LikeNumber = 55, ForwardingNumber = 21 },
            new Article { Author = "author1", ReadingNumber = 11, LikeNumber = 35, ForwardingNumber = 79 },
            new Article { Author = "author2", ReadingNumber = 25, LikeNumber = 77, ForwardingNumber = 39 },
        };
```

Now I don't know how to use Linq or anything others to convert this into Highchart column table data, which is like this:

```
categories: ['author1','author2']

series: [{
        name: 'TotalReadingNumber',
        data: [60, 25]
    }, {
        name: 'TotalLikeNumber',
        data: [90, 77]
    }, {
        name: 'TotalForwardNumber',
        data: [100, 39]
    }]
```

I've tired to use linq and Foreach Method to generate data:

```
var authorData=
    (from a in articleList
     group a by a.Author into g
     select new {
       Author = g.Key,
       TotalReading = g.Sum(a=>a.ReadingNumber),
       TotalLikes = g.Sum(a=>a.LikeNumber),
       .......
    }).ToList()
```

Then I use `ForEach` Method to get every property I need

```
               var totalReading = new AuthorData()
                {
                    name = "TotalReading",
                    data = new List<string>()
                };
                authorData.ForEach(a => totalRead.data.Add(a.TotalRead.ToString()));
```

At last I combine them into result,

```
var result =
 {
    Authors=authorData.Select(a=>a.Author).ToList(),
    series = new List<AuthorData>{totalReading,totalLike,totalForwrad.....}
}
```

I think it's so complicated. How can I simplify this solution?

Comment: Hi @ichPotatodeCXY, You have used highcharts tag, but the problem doesn't seem to be about a chart - rather about data. If you'll have problems with Highcharts then please provide a demo with hard-coded, exemplary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you did not specify what your input is and why it should look like the expected output. But I guess this solution should build your expected output. I used reflection to build it. If you add or remove any integer properties, they will automatically be added or removed from your output string.

EDIT: After you edited your question, I saw that you need to calculate sums of your properties. This was not clear in your original question. This is the updated code:

```
List<Article> input = new List<Article>
{
    new Article { Author = "author1", ReadingNumber = 49, LikeNumber = 55, ForwardingNumber = 74 },
    new Article { Author = "author1", ReadingNumber = 141, LikeNumber = 78, ForwardingNumber = 38 },
    new Article { Author = "author2", ReadingNumber = 106, LikeNumber = 38, ForwardingNumber = 39 },
};
        
var grouped = input.GroupBy(x => x.Author).Select(x => new
{
    Author = x.Key,
    TotalReadingNumber = x.Sum(y=>y.ReadingNumber),
    TotalLikeNumber = x.Sum(y=>y.LikeNumber),
    TotalForwardingNumber = x.Sum(y=>y.ForwardingNumber),
}).ToList();
    
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
output.AppendLine("xAxis: {");
output.AppendLine("categories: [");
output.AppendLine(string.Join(",", input.Select(x => $"'{x.Author}'")));
output.AppendLine("]");
output.AppendLine("},"); 
output.Append("series: [");
bool first = true;
foreach(var property in grouped.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First().GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(int)))
{
    if(!first)
    {
        output.Append(", ");
    }
    output.AppendLine("{");
    output.AppendLine("name: 'Total" + property.Name + "',");
    output.AppendLine("data: [" + string.Join(",", grouped.Select(x => property.GetValue(x))) + "]");
    output.Append("}");
    first = false;
}
output.AppendLine("]");
```

If you don't want to use reflection, because you need performance or because you don't want to change your output dynamically when you change your `Article` class, you can also use several `string.Join` calls like I did with the categories, and hardcode the values like `TotalReadingNumber`, `TotalLikeNumber` etc.

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/I88ZHD

Comment: It's a promising solution, but I want to save result as Json string into database  so that I can read it in another controller and return it to front. Could you plz check my code I updated and see that whether using reflection can make similar result.

Comment: I updated the answer. Now it should match your problem.